# how to create functions or views from within a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, view

in a stored procedure i know you can create tables or database or schema, but is it possible to create a function or a view:
here is what i tried:

```
create PROCEDURE schemaName.asd()
begin
DECLARE stmt VARCHAR(255);

SET stmt := concat('CREATE FUNCTION schemaName.asdsfasdf() RETURNS int BEGIN return 1; end;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;

EXECUTE stmt;
end;
```

when i do

```
call schemaName.asd()$$
```

and i get an ERROR CODE 1064

is it possible to create here functions or views?
if yes how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    declare @SqlStmt varchar(500)

    select @SqlStmt='CREATE FUNCTION schemaName.asdsfasdf() 
                     RETURNS int BEGIN return 1; end';
    exec(@SqlStmt)
```